# Could the compiler have optimized the dynamic_cast away?

Tags: c++

I have stepped onto code like this:

```cpp
dynamic_cast<A*>(p)->foo();
```

which is of course terrible, since when dynamic_cast returns 0, you have an undefined behavior.

Then I thought, one terrible surprise that it could bring, is that since when p can be cast to a A* it is the same as doing a static_cast, and when it cannot you get undefined behavior, the compiler could change the dynamic_cast into a static_cast and keep a conforming behavior.
That said, I tried the following code with compiler explorer:

```cpp
class A {
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class B final: public A {
    public:
    void foo();
    void bar() override;
};

void h();

void f(A* const p)
{
    dynamic_cast<B*>(p)->foo();
}
```

and to my surprise every compiler kept the dynamic_cast call. Is there something that eluded me or do compilers simply do not do a possible optimization?

Comment: They can't do an optimization, since they still have to do the `dynamic_cast`. It returning `nullptr` is your problem, not the compilers.

Comment: Think of a case where you have two child-classes of `A`. How would the compiler know that the cast from `p` could be transformed into a `static_cast<B*>`? It doesn't really know what kind object the pointer `p` might actually be pointing to.

Comment: @ChrisMM Please expand on "they still have to do the `dynamic_cast`". Why is that the case? What observable behaviour does it perform in all possible well-defined cases here?

Comment: Looks like you expect the compiler writers to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/29/my-most-embarrassing-mistakes-as-a-programmer-so-far/ . There is no practical need for such optimization (a warning that a part of dynamic_cast functionality is not used, so it can be replaced with static_cast, would be nice, though).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude then how can static down cast work, if it had been written instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's the point. In the case you describe, the full expression has undefined behaviour. Compilers make use of UB in exactly this way all the time. However this simply appears not to be a scenario they take advantage of at the moment

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica The Standard states _The value of a failed cast to pointer type is the null pointer value of the required result type_, so if you are putting in a `dynamic_cast`, then should the compiler not follow the rules of what it is supposed to do? When does the compiler get the option to ignore what the standards say, and do what it wants instead?

Comment: @ChrisMM When the program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisMM: To clarify, Undefined Behavior in C++ can do anything, including changing the the result of past operations. This allows the compiler to pretend that `dynamic_cast` did _not_ return a null pointer in this specific case.

Comment: Or, put another way, the compiler is permitted to _make use of_ the fact that, in the example above, there is actually only one case where the program is well-formed, so the `dynamic_cast` is not necessary. You might think this is nitpicking or daydreaming, but it isn't. This is exactly the sort of optimisation compilers perform all the time. It's the very _reason_ for UB.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica (and MSalters) Yes, I suppose that is correct, although in this case it makes me rather uneasy.

Comment: @ChrisMM Why is that?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Since `dynamic_cast` is supposed to return `nullptr`. I realize in this case, performing `->foo` afterward is UB either way, but for debugging purposes, I'd rather my debugger complain to me that the object was `nullptr` as opposed to something else. Granted, I'd never write code like that anyway.

Comment: @ChrisMM Ah, well, welcome to C++ ;) `dynamic_cast` _does_ return `nullptr`, under such circumstances, _in a well-defined program_. FWIW, notice that current compilers _don't_ make use of this opportunity (per the question) and, even if they did, I'd expect them to only do so in release. So your debugger remains unaffected.

Comment: Is this even a problem from the compiler's point of view? It needs to dynamically dispatch a virtual function call, but **you are telling** it that the dynamic dispatch is really a static dispatch (by doing the cast). So... it can just do that, and is indeed required to do it. All it needs to worry about would be `this` if any members were used inside `foo` but seeing how it's not even defined that isn't the case. So... no problem for the compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see why the optimisation wouldn't be possible. The compiler can see that only two cases exist:

- The dynamic type of the operand is `B`, so the cast can be static
- The dynamic type of the operand is some other type deriving from `A`, in which case the result is `nullptr` and the full expression has undefined behaviour

*(No types deriving from `B` are possible, due to the `final` specifier. This is convenient because, if they were possible, a static cast would not necessarily be an adequate substitution for the dynamic cast — multiple inheritance and sidecasts would have to be considered, and there may not be sufficient information in this translation unit to do so. Link-time optimisation would further mitigate that, but in practice the majority of optimisations like this happen at compile-time, and any platform supporting things like `dlopen` would also veto the possibility.)*

So, we have only one case that results in a well-defined program.

Since compilers are permitted to assume that the input does not have undefined behaviour, if removing all code paths that result in UB leaves you with just one possible outcome, then the compiler can just assume that'll always be the outcome. That's the core reason for undefined behaviour to be a thing, to permit optimisations like this, and compilers perform them all the time to make your code nice and fast.

I'll admit to being slightly surprised that the mainstream compilers don't make use of that opportunity in this case. I'd at least expect a warning about a redundant `dynamic_cast`; still, it's possible that some static analysers give you this.

Comment: I could see this happen "unintentionally" if a compiler happens to represent the two cases as two branches internally, and if the optimizer then spots the nullptr UB in one branch. The generic case is probably more common.

Comment: @MSalters Exactly, that's the sort of optimisation that can be (and is often) performed. I'll admit to being a little surprised that it isn't in this case, but what the hey

Comment: @Kit. Alright, yeah I think you're right. I'll tweak that. Thanks :)